# Convert Microsoft Office .doc files to Office 2007 .docx file from the command line

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, conversion, microsoft-office-2007

I need to convert Microsoft Office Word .doc files into the new format (.docx) of Office 2007.
I need it to be done via the command line since it's an application where people upload .doc files, and I want them automatically to be converted to .docx.

I can live with a link to a downloadable .exe file if you can provide one, and C++ code will be even better.

Comment: never heard of this use case before... usually it's in the *other* direction :)

Answer (score 3):

This article http://www.labnol.org/software/bulk-convert-office-documents-in-2007-format/4291/
describes a method using tools downloadable from Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

If you want something like code, try the [JODConverter](http://artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) Java library.

JODConverter automates all conversions supported by OpenOffice.org, including `.doc` and `.docx` files.

I used the library, and it does a good job.